# Reshape layer present but doesn't reshape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi so while adding a simple and trivial *Keras* `Reshape` layer to reshape my images from a Convolution

```
    decoder = BatchNormalization()(decoder)
    decoder = Reshape((224 * 512, n_classes), input_shape=(224, 512, 3))(decoder)

    predictions = Activation('softmax')(decoder)
```

I get this error when I run it

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_13 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 224, 512, 3)
```

The weird this is that its present in the graph:

```
batch_normalization_13 (Batc (None, 224, 512, 3)       12
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 114688, 3)         0
_________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)   (None, 114688, 3)         0
______________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, the error is complaining *with the batch size* so your final output is 3 dimensional as seen in summary. The problem is your targets, y train is not reshaped. You need to reshape your target array, the one you pass into fit to a 3D tensor of shape `(samples, 114688, 3)`.